# Как определяется «тривиальность» ответа?

Tags: поддержка, ответы, комментарии

Оставил [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464690/github-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0#autocomment592682) на вопрос. «Тривиальный ответ преобразован в комментарий». В каких случаях происходит преобразование?

Comment: Кстати, зачем вы пишете "Спасибо" в конце своих *ответов*?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, проявление вежливости, для смягчения, поскольку ответ может показаться вопрошающему жёстким. Возможно, иногда «Спасибо» и лишнее. Спасибо :) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Преобразование происходит, если ответ содержит ссылку на вопрос или ответ в сети Stack Exchange, и притом очень короткий  - конкретное ограничение по длине не было оглашено.

Чтобы этого избежать, нужно либо написать более подробный ответ, объясняющий, **как** материал по ссылке решает проблему, либо не писать ответ вообще, а отметить вопрос как дубликат предыдущего (если он этим является).

Comment: А короткие без ссылок?

Comment: @ Qwertiy,  минимум 30 символов. Если чуть больше и без ссылок на проекты Stack Exchange — вроде ответ выводится нормально. Спасибо.